# Height defined in millimeters wrong in mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I'm trying to make sure that an `<img>` has a certain height, in real units (cm or mm), regardless of the device's screen size.

so my css rule has

```
img.class_of_image
{
 height:34.3mm
}
```

and it works in -my- PC too.
but when I visit the page with my mobile device (a really small one)
the height renders something like 25mm.

How can I solve this problem ?

I added this tag inside `<head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

the demo is in this link:
http://webtasarimveprogramlama.com/cetvel/alternatif-1/

and the device I'm using to test is : Samsung Galaxy Young S5360

### Edit

I tested the URL with this site:
http://www.brickandmobile.com/mobile-emulator/

it renders the height as 30mm for Galaxy Note,
so there is apparently something wrong.

The height rule "scales" with device size, which I don't want.

### Edit 2:

Really? No way ?
I'm open to a jQuery or any other solution. Just need a way to make sure that img has certain size. Please don't tell me it is impossible :)

Comment: The problem could be that the device doesn't render images accurately in size.

Comment: But shouldn't the CSS rule impose the image size on the device ?

Comment: It's still up to the device to scale it properly.  You said that it's a really small device; maybe that's one of the design tradeoffs the engineers adopted when they created the device.

Comment: I tested with emulators, it has different height in different devices. Please see my edit.

Comment: How does that change what I said?

Comment: It does not. However, if every device's engineers set it to scale images however they want, well, then how do I make an img have a certain height?

Comment: You may not be able to.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS `mm` unit doesn't actually represent real-life millimeters, it just represents 3.78px.

Source: http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/.

Comment: Thanks. Although this is bad news, this helps. Any idea how to set a dimension to real-life units ?